# Determine significant transitions in data values

Tags: data-visualization, quantiles, scatterplot

I don't have much experience with statistics and suspect this is a common problem with a common solution. Normally I would just eye-ball the data and call it a day, but at some point you ought to learn the right way to do things.

I have a dataset of about 17,000 areas with a [cumulative distribution](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-window.html):

```
gid          st_area2d           cume_dist 
9810     0.0000280288363734472   0.0000568052715291979 
10804    0.0000387003730889654   0.0001136105430583960 
3087     0.0000492940355178313   0.0001704158145875940 
7037     0.0000504638710612963   0.0002272210861167920
...
```

When I make a scatter plot of the area and percentile there are two clear transitions- one where the percentiles were very small and another where they become very large (relatively):

[image: CSUM Chart]

How can I best determine exactly which percentile marks those transitions? So I want a way to determine that somewhere around the 95th percentile my areas get much larger very quickly and somewhere are 98 it levels off again.

My guess is comparing the slope between points; at both transitions the slope will become significantly less steep. I suspect there is standard method, but I don't know the terminology or have the background to defend one method over another.